# Read the n-th line of multiple files into a single output

Tags: bash, syntax, sed

I have some dump files called `dump_mydump_0.cfg`, `dump_mydump_250.cfg`, ..., all the way up to `dump_mydump_40000.cfg`. For each dump file, I'd like to take the 16th line out, read them, and put them into one single file.

I'm using `sed`, but I came across some syntax errors. Here's what I have so far:

```
for lineNo in 16 ;
for fileNo in 0,40000 ; do
    sed -n  "${lineNo}{p;q;}" dump_mydump_file${lineNo}.cfg >> data.txt
done
```

Comment: You're shy `do`'s and `done`'s in your snippet.

Comment: If the given answer addresses your problem correctly, it is nice to mark it as answer; click on the tick below the voting arrows if you want to accept the answer. Glad it helped! (:

Answer (score 1):

Considering your files are named with intervals of `250`, you should get it working using:

```
for lineNo in 16; do
    for fileNo in {0..40000..250}; do
        sed -n "${lineNo}{p;q;}" dump_mydump_file${fileNo}.cfg >> data.txt
    done
done
```

Note both the bash syntax corrections -- `do`, `done`, and `{0..40000..250}` --, and the input file name, that should depend on `${fileNo}` instead of `${lineNo}`.

Comment: I'm wondering why one would loop over the number 16 in the first place?  Why not have `lineNo=16` and get rid of the outer loop?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, with (GNU) awk:

```
awk "FNR==16{print;nextfile}" dump_mydump_{0..40000..250}.cfg > data.txt
```

(I used the filenames as shown in the OP as opposed to the ones which would have been generated by the bash for loop, if corrected to work. But you can edit as needed.)

The advantage is that you don't need the for loop, and you don't need to spawn 160 processes. But it's not a huge advantage.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ns '16wdata.txt' dump_mydump_{0..40000..250}.cfg
```