# Using awk command to add an extra column

Tags: awk, ubuntu-12.04

So yesterday I used sed command to read the n-th line of multiple files into a single output
[Read the n-th line of multiple files into a single output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865990/read-the-n-th-line-of-multiple-files-into-a-single-output)
and I was able to generate a data.txt file which looks like this:

```
0 0 0 
-1.08051e-16 -1.73991e-16 -1.79157e-16 
-1.02169e-15 -1.19283e-15 5.92632e-16 
3.41114e-16 -1.02211e-15 3.19436e-15 
......
```

Note that they are all position data represent x, y and z axis. Now I just want to add one more column using awk command to represent time step which correspond the number of my dump file like 0 250 500...all the way to 40000.

Comment: For what do you need the additional column? If it is for plotting the data with `gnuplot`, then you can generate this from within the program. But that is only guessed from your tags... not the best way to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but adding a column is pretty trivial in `awk`. You can do:

```
$ echo '0 0 0                                       
-1.08051e-16 -1.73991e-16 -1.79157e-16 
-1.02169e-15 -1.19283e-15 5.92632e-16                                             
3.41114e-16 -1.02211e-15 3.19436e-15 ' | awk 'BEGIN{val=0}{print $0,val;val+=250}'
0 0 0 0
-1.08051e-16 -1.73991e-16 -1.79157e-16  250
-1.02169e-15 -1.19283e-15 5.92632e-16  500
3.41114e-16 -1.02211e-15 3.19436e-15  750
```